# Sql query to join/union two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am looking for some suggestions to build a query to join table A & table B to get the output as table C. It looks like I need to be able to union the two tables and build a cross tab query. The data shown below are just examples as the dates in the two tables would be changing every month. Note: the dates in the two tables will not overlap. For example, below Table B will never have FutureDates as June or July. and vice-versa

```
Table A
Product Location HistoryDate HistorySales ... more columns
 A         X         June      100
 A         X         July      200

Table B
Product Location FutureDate FutureSales   ... more columns
 A         X         August    150
 A         X         Sept      50

Table C
Product Location June July August September ... other columns from A & B
 A         X     100  200    150    50
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You would need dynamic SQL or just hardcode all 12 months and have nulls or have Month1,Month2,Month3,Month4 and maybe pass back someother way what these columns represent.

Comment: @Daniel, A pivot is exactly what he wants.

Comment: The question is too vague. Are the dates in A/B expressed as a string of the month name, and only one record per month? Will there never be more than 12 records across A and B, given that they "won't overlap"? It's not obvious, but I'm guessing there are other Product+Location combinations? How do you plan to display "other columns from A & B" in C, given that one row in C is made up of multiple rows from A and B - which row of A/B would the data come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been tested in SQL Server 2008 R2. I believe everything here will work in 2005 as well. 2005, as far as I remember, introduced PIVOT and OVER among other things. If you find any problems just let me know.

```
DECLARE @Products TABLE
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
    , Name VARCHAR(30)
);

INSERT INTO @Products
VALUES ('Dummies Guide to Querying'), ('SQL Design Patterns');

DECLARE @OldProducts TABLE
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
    , ProductID INT
    , Location CHAR(2)
    , HistoryDate DATE
    , Sales INT
);

INSERT INTO @OldProducts
VALUES (1, 'CO', '20100601', 100)
    , (1, 'CO', '20100701', 200)
    , (1, 'CA', '20100526', 150)
    , (2, 'CA', '20100601', 175);

DECLARE @NewProducts TABLE
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
    , ProductID INT
    , Location CHAR(2)
    , FutureDate DATE
    , PredictedSales INT
);

INSERT INTO @NewProducts
VALUES (1, 'CO', '20110401', 200)
    , (1, 'CO', '20110601', 250)
    , (1, 'CA', '20110401', 150)
    , (2, 'CA', '20110301', 180)
    , (3, 'WA', '20110301', 100);

WITH AllProduts AS
(
    SELECT
        Products.Name
        , OldProducts.Location
        , DATENAME(MONTH, OldProducts.HistoryDate) AS MonthValue
        , OldProducts.Sales
    FROM @OldProducts AS OldProducts
    INNER JOIN @Products AS Products
        ON Products.ID = OldProducts.ProductID

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        Products.Name
        , NewProducts.Location
        , DATENAME(MONTH, NewProducts.FutureDate) AS MonthValue
        , NewProducts.PredictedSales AS Sales
    FROM @NewProducts AS NewProducts
    INNER JOIN @Products AS Products
        ON Products.ID = NewProducts.ProductID
)
SELECT
    Name
    , Location
    , [January]
    , [Febuary]
    , [March]
    , [April]
    , [May]
    , [June]
    , [July]
    , [August]
    , [September]
    , [October]
    , [November]
    , [December]
FROM AllProduts
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Sales)
    FOR MonthValue
    IN
    (
        [January]
        , [Febuary]
        , [March]
        , [April]
        , [May]
        , [June]
        , [July]
        , [August]
        , [September]
        , [October]
        , [November]
        , [December]
    )
) PivotedTable
ORDER BY Name, Location;
```