# How to merge two tables without using join and union?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I have two tables with same column names.

Example:

```
id name         id name
-------         --------
1  xyz          2  abc
```

I want the answer like this

```
id name
-------
1  xyx
2  abc
```

How will I get the above answer without using `join` or `union`?

Database should be Postgres or SQL Server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sql query to join/union two tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696586/sql-query-to-join-union-two-tables)

Comment: PostgreSQL comes from Postgres SQL, not Postgre. It is very common misbelief.

Comment: yes...Join or Union should not be used

Comment: Why don't you want to use `UNION` or `JOIN`?

Comment: The only thing I can think of, is to create a temp table and insert all values from both tables there. Then select from the temp table.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL

```
SELECT unnest(ids) id
      ,unnest(vals) "name"
FROM (
    SELECT string_to_array(a.id || ',' || b.id, ',') ids
          ,string_to_array(a.val || ',' || b.val, ',') vals
    FROM a,b
    ) t
```

---

A simplified one:

```
select unnest(array[a.id,b.id]) id
      ,unnest(array[a.val,b.val]) "name"
from a,b
```

---

Using CTE

```
with cte as(
select * from a
),cte1 as(
select * from b
)
select * from cte
union
select * from cte1 order by id
```

---

As per [Giorgos Betsos's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34153194/how-to-merge-two-tables-without-using-join-and-union/34153704?noredirect=1#comment56053288_34153194)

```
drop table  if exists t;
create temp table t as  select id,val from a;
insert into t select id,val from b;
select * from t;
```

Comment: `FROM a, b` is a sort of a `JOIN` operation, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is, Lets keep an eye on OP's comment

Comment: Technically you are still using a "join" - although not an explicit `join` operator, but `from a,b` is still a (cross) join.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  I knew that.OP's question is unclear and I assume that OP wants to avoid the use of UNION or JOIN keyword . Let's wait for OP's comment _Should I delete this_ ??

Comment: We don't know what the OP wants. Maybe it is indeed about avoiding the _keyword_ join, not a join in general. Maybe it's something completely different. A very strange requirement nonetheless